# How to add new records in access via vba

Tags: vba, excel

'Hi all,
I made VBA, this code add new records into access database. But the problem is when multiple run the vba i get error message as "Unrecognized database format" "Run time error 3343.
Can any one suggest me why i am getting this error. My code is below

Comment: Show your code please..

Comment: PrivateSubExportNewData()
DimWsAsWorksheet
DimrsAsNewRecordset
SetWs=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
j=3
DoWhileNotWs.Cells(j,2)=""
j=j+1
Loop
Ifrs.State=1Thenrs.Close
rs.Open"Select*fromDatawhereid=0",cn.db,adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic
IfNotrs.EOFThenExitSub
Fori=4Toj-1
rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("AssignedDate")=Date'Caseassigndate
rs.Fields("LNumber")=Ws.Cells(i,2)'LockboxNumber
rs.Fields("DepositDate")=Ws.Cells(i,3)'DepositDate
rs.Fields("BNumber")=Ws.Cells(i,4)'CustomerBatchNumber
rs.Fields("CNumber")=Ws.Cells(i,8)'CheckNumber
me'Username
rs.Update
Nexti
rs.Close
cn.db.Close
Setrs=Nothing

EndSub

Comment: Option Explicit

Public db As New ADODB.Connection
Public str As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

  If db.State = 1 Then db.Close
  
  'db.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\1245.4578\1245\Users\1245\1245\Daily report\Team Database Do not delete\REPORT.accdb;"


  
  db.Open
 
 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using VBA to send data from Excel to Access.  Please see the links below.  Those links should answer pretty much all of your questions about this topic.

http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/dao_ado.htm

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacexportado

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacexportdao

http://www.datawright.com.au/excel_resources/excel_access_and_ado.htm

You can import from Excel into Access as well.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

Comment: Thanks, My code also works file. when multiple users use or multiple users export data Access corrupt. it give error message as "Unrecognized database format" "Run time error 3343. Any idea to rid out from this.